# Adding a post receive hook in github

Tags: git, github, githooks

I'd like to add a post receive server side hook to a private repo in github.com. I am aware of the "webhooks" feature but I'd like to add a powershell script as a part of the post receive hook. I don't see a way to do it on github's website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. It would require Github to allow user-submitted scripts to run on their servers, which poses a considerable security risk.

If you want actions triggered upon push-to-Github, you will need to set up your own server which gets notified via a Webhook, and then (if necessary) pulls from Github and executes the actions you need it to do.